# Can’t find a way to break the fourth pillar in the links awakening remake

Tags: zelda-links-awakening-2019

I’m in eagle’s tower and Im trying to break the last pillar but I can’t! I can’t get the ball to there due to a huge gap the ball cant go over, can someone help me get there with the ball so I can solve the riddle?

Comment: This website seems to have a walkthrough: https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2019-09-20-zelda-links-awakening-walkthrough-guide-6812

Comment: It would help if you included a picture of the room, or some other information to help us understand exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: This was challenging in the original and GBC Links Awakening too. I strongly suspect (but cannot confirm) that a walkthrough for the original Links Awakening showing how to break the 4th pillar will be valid for the Switch remake - the games are very similar.